# SiteMile Auction Theme - Show end date of auction?

Tags: wordpress, date

I'm currently helping out a friend with his website, wordpress with a SiteMile auction theme on it, but one bit of it is proving above my skill level at the moment.

There's a countdown on the site, that shows up twice. Once as a "Ends on" and once as a "Time left", which in the case of the latter is fine. I'm tasked with changing the first one, to show the end date and time, but no matter how I've tried to do it, I can't make it work.

The code is as follows

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/cal.png" width="20" height="20" /> 
    <h3><?php echo __("Slutter den","AuctionTheme"); ?>:</h3>
    <p class="expiration_auction_p"><?php echo ($closed == "0" ? ($ending - current_time('timestamp',0)) 
    : __("Expired/Closed","AuctionTheme"));?></p>

<!--    <p><?php echo ($closed == "0" ? AuctionTheme_prepare_seconds_to_words($ending - current_time('timestamp',0)) 
        : __("Expired/Closed","AuctionTheme")); ?></p> -->
```

Any ideas how to make it show the end date from just changing this?

```
$ending = get_post_meta($pid, 'ending', true);
```

Here's what $ending is referring to.

Comment: So what do you see then?

Comment: I see a countdown, formatted like " 48 Days 22 Hr 42 Min 45 Sec "

Comment: I have no idea of wordpress (lucky me) but if you want to show a static value then why not show it as such - a static value?

Comment: Well that's the thing... I tried but failed repeatedly. I've managed to get it display the original date of the posting but I can't for the life of me, figure out how to make it show the end date.

Answer (score 1):

AuctionTheme_prepare_seconds_to_words($ending - current_time('timestamp',0))

This shows the ending date.